# Confused about timezone,dateutil.parser.parse ?

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone

I have a variable:`data_datetime = dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime'])`
I print it out ,it is  `2016-03-12 01:49:43.082514+00:00`
And I save into database :`obj.update_time = data_datetime`

But the database's time is wrong,It save `2016-03-12 01:49:43.082514+08`  (It add a timezone 8 hours)
It should save `2016-03-12 01:49:43.082514+00:00` or `2016-03-12 09:49:43.082514+08`

I felt very confused. How can I save the right time into database???

---

I have another try `current_utc_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)`
and I print it out : `2016-03-12 02:01:58.631653+00:00`
And when it save to database`obj.update(id=id,update_time=current_utc_time)`
It save the right time I want : `2016-03-12 10:01:58.364853+08`

I don't know why `data_datetime = dateutil.parser.parse(data['datetime'])` can't not save the right time
Please help me,thank you

I found a difference: one is use `obj.update_time = data_datetime` ,another is use `obj.update(id=id,update_time=current_utc_time)`
If it is the root cause, How can I save the right time I want???

Answer (score 0):

When you start out from Python datetime object, it gets serialized properly to the database. When you round trip from a database datetime object, parsed to a Python object, them serialized back, the timezone is getting corrupted.  The dateutil package docs for the parse function (https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) talk about  `ignoretz` as well `tzinfos` parameters, and the fact that it will make naive guesses about timezones. Coupled with the fact that all the examples in those docs show a two digit timezone offset, my guess is you need to replace 00:00 with 00 in the strings you are parsing. Or, use the tzinfos parameter somehow to map the ISO8601 timezone offset style to the UTC time zone so the parser isn't making incorrect guesses on data it can't parse.